# converting xml document to data table in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services

I'm trying to read a simple webservice (REST) and populate a drop down box in my C# desktop application. I;m using .net 2.0

Following is my web service return xml

```
<sections type="array">
 <section>
  <name>Standing</name>
  <created-at type="datetime">2011-10-23T23:17:54+05:30</created-at>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2011-10-23T23:17:54+05:30</updated-at>
  <id type="integer">1</id>
  <status type="integer">1</status>
  <service-charge type="float">0.0</service-charge>
 </section>
 <section>
  <name>VIP</name>
  <created-at type="datetime">2011-10-30T11:27:05+05:30</created-at>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2011-10-30T11:27:05+05:30</updated-at>
  <id type="integer">2</id>
  <status type="integer">1</status>
  <service-charge type="float">10.0</service-charge>
 </section>
```

and in the following code I'm trying to convert the xml document to a data table

```
  public DataTable getSections() {
    String url = "http://<site_url>/sections.xml";
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    HttpHandler handle = new HttpHandler();
    StreamReader sr = handle.executeGET(url);
    String xml = "";
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        xml  += sr.ReadLine();
    }
    XmlDataDocument doc = new XmlDataDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(doc);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(xmlReader);
    t = ds.Tables[0];
    return t;
}
```

and in the last segment I'm trying to bind it to my drop down box (cmbSections)

```
DataTable t = sec.getSections();
cmbSections.DataSource = t;
cmbSections.DisplayMember = "name";
cmbSections.ValueMember = "id";
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
Cannot bind to the new display member.
Parameter name: newDisplayMember
```

What am i missing here, please help, I'm new to C# world

Comment: If you place a breakpoint at the return line of getSections, what do you see in the DataSet?

Comment: Do you have a schema for the source xml?

Comment: Hi Sq33G, I think I'm getting some values, but dont know how to debug, But when I use 't.GetType();' I'm getting {System.Data.DataTable} as the output, is there any special section I should look at, thanks for the answer

Comment: Hi curtisk, I'm not sure what  you ask by schema for the source xml, could u please explain, thanks

Comment: @sameera207, well of course.  [`GetType()` is inherited from `object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx).  You need to learn and understand the API you're working with.  Look at the `Rows` and `Columns` collections on the `DataTable` to answer @sq33G's question.

Comment: Actually, there should be a magnifying glass you can click on that lets you inspect the contents of your DataSet. Clicking on the far left margin of the line where you want to break should mark the line maroon (very dark brown-red) and place a maroon dot in the margin. When you run with debug (F5, or the regular green arrow), execution should break at that mark. Click on the dot again to remove it.

Comment: Hi @sq33G, thanks for the reply, I got it working with another way, dont know if that is the standard way of parsing. I updated it as an answer, thanks again for the valuable answer. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use extension method to support conversion of XElement to Datatable. You can add this method to any of your utility classes. Make sure the class is static.

```
public static class XElementExtensions 
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this XElement element) 
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string rawXml = element.ToString();
        ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(rawXml));
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }


    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IEnumerable<XElement> elements) 
    {
        return ToDataTable(new XElement("Root", elements));
    }
}
```

How to use

```
//Add logic to store xml data in file or string & read accordingly here.
string file = Server.MapPath("~/Data.xml");
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(file);
var query = from b in document.Elements("sections").Elements("section")
                  select b;

DataTable table = query.ToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple way to convert XML to DataSet:**

```
        StringReader strr = new StringReader(strXML);
        XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(strr);
        YourTypeDataSet dstest = new YourTypeDataSet();
        dstest.ReadXml(xtr);

        if (dstest.Tables.Count > 0) ...
```

for correct conversion, you replace your type DataSet in place of:
            DataSet dstest = new DataSet();

;)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following code, but I'm not quit sure if this is the correct way to do it

(This parse the above same xml)

```
public DataTable getSections() {
        String url = "http://<site_url>/sections.xml/sections.xml";
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        t.Columns.Add("id", typeof(String));
        t.Columns.Add("name", typeof(String));

        HttpHandler handle = new HttpHandler();
        StreamReader sr = handle.executeGET(url);
        String xml = "";
        List<String> id = new List<string>();
        List<String> name = new List<string>();

        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            xml  += sr.ReadLine();
        }
        XmlDataDocument doc = new XmlDataDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(doc);
        while (xmlReader.Read()){
            if (xmlReader.IsStartElement()) {
                String b = xmlReader.Name;
                switch (xmlReader.Name) { 
                    case "sections":
                        break;
                    case "section":
                        break;
                    case "id":
                        if (xmlReader.Read())
                        {
                            id.Add(xmlReader.Value.Trim());
                        }
                        break;
                    case "name":
                        if (xmlReader.Read())
                        {
                            name.Add(xmlReader.Value.Trim());

                        }
                        break;

                }
            }
        }

        int counter = 0;

        foreach (String i in id) {
            DataRow r = t.NewRow();
            r["id"] = i;
            r["name"] = name[counter];
            t.Rows.Add(r);    
            counter += 1;
        }
        return t;
    }
```

Thanks for the comments :D 
Your valuable comments are always welcome